# Best way to convert Javascript Ajax to jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whats the best way to convert this code to jquery? I tried it this way but noticed that internet explorer gives me trouble with this. So I decided to do it with jQuery but I see a lot of methods but I dont know how to make the same function with it.

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "inc/form_rest.php?q=" + str + "&prevvalue=" + prevvalue + "&value=" + value + "&vehicletype=" + vehicletype, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: The best way is to learn jQuery. The easy way is to follow the good advice given in response to your question.

Comment: I understand but I have to choose for the easy way since I am in a hurry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest would be to use [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) :

```
$.get("inc/form_rest.php",
    {q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value, vehicletype:vehicletype},
    function(html){
       $('#'+id).html(html);
    }
);
```

Note that I let jQuery build the url, which will also ensure that the urlencoding is properly done.

As you're only using the response to fill an element, you could also have used

```
$('#'+id).load(
   "inc/form_rest.php?q=" + str + "&prevvalue=" + prevvalue + "&value=" + value + "&vehicletype=" + vehicletype
);
```

Comment: `prevvalue` should go with quotes on the q parameter?

Comment: @TomSarduy No, you don't need to put the property names between quotes.

Comment: What does the last function do? function(html){$('#'+id).html(html);} I call the function somewhere else in the script if thats that

Comment: It's the same as `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=html`, in a more jqueryiesque way.

Comment: Thanks a lot both ways work! I chose for the first one as it looks more secure.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy, ju just need to call one method:

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype) {
  if (str=="")
  {
    $('#' + id).html("");
    return;
  } 
  $.get("inc/form_rest.php", 
        {"prevvalue": prevvalue, "value":value /*and so on*/},
        function(data) {
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;  //this is compatible, no jQuery needed!
        }
  );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a GET request, so it would make sense to use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) instead:

```
$.get("inc/form_rest.php", {
    q : str,
    prevvalue : prevvalue,
    value : value,
    vehicletype : vehicletype
}, function(response) {
    $('#' + id).html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to bother about browsers while using jQuery. Just use jQuery Ajax [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
method.
Use

```
$.get('inc/form_rest.php',  // URL
      {q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value,vehicletype:vehicletype}, // Data
      function(data) {
      // Do post Ajax things here
});
```

Comment: @JanDvorak: was about to update my answer. Let me know if I should add something more

Comment: Thank you but how do I make it so that I can give the function a name and paramteres like I did with javascript so I can call it

Comment: @SinanSamet: I have updated my answer. Just visit jQuery doc link, you will get the rest of the things.

Comment: @Downvoter: May I know the reason behind the reward?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/form_rest.php?q='+str+'&prevvalue='+prevvalue+'&value='+value+'&vehicletype='+vehicletype,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=data;
    }

});
```

or simple

```
$.get('inc/form_rest.php?q='+str+'&prevvalue='+prevvalue+'&value='+value+'&vehicletype='+vehicletype, function(data) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following :

1. Remove code which checks browser and then creates **xmlhttp**  object.
2. You don't need any explicit callback method like  **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function**.
3. Directly put your **jQuery** ajax method call

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype){
      var request = $.ajax({
          url: "inc/form_rest.php",
          type: "GET",
          data: { "str" : str, 
                  "prevvalue" : prevvalue, 
                  "value" : value, 
                  "vehicletype" : vehicletype
          },
          'success': function(){
             //successful request
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your example:

```
var url = "inc/form_rest.php?q="+str+"&prevvalue="+prevvalue+"&value="+value+"&vehicletype="+vehicletype;

$.get(url,function(data){
 $("#"+id).html(data); 
 });
```